# Public chat for virtual coworking

Tags: gratis, web-apps, chat, hosted, communication

I want to create virtual coworking chat room, where people can share what they are working on and talk to earch other, while working on their every day tasks during a day.

So I need hosted chat service with following features:

- status messages displayed on the contact list, to publish current task user is working on
- /me command - for messages like: "user1 is now working on task 1", "user1 completed task 1", etc.

It would be great if it also had:

- guest user access, not requiring registration
- video streaming feature
- private chats between users

I am not a developer, so I'm searching for already existing solution.

I already considered:

- IRC - no status messages, quite complicated for newbies to jump in
- ICQ, Google Hangouts - no status messages, no /me command
- A bunch of online chat rooms - could not find any with neither status messages nor /me command

Comment: "messages displayed on the contact list, to publish current task user is working on": Do you mean that a list of users should be visible, with the "status" (last /me message) visible below each name? Is that a strict requirement?

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul, user list with status messages below each name is a strict requirement. But no need for the status to be last /me command, user should synchronize himself. Would be great of course if I could introduce my own command instead of /me, that would also change user status automatically, but I'm afraid it is too complex requirement, and I'll not find such solution.

Answer (score 2):

[Slack](https://slack.com/) may be the most suitable, if it doesn't have the functionality that you need out the box, then they do have plenty of add-ons that may be worth looking at.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of Slack's user list with status messages below each name, thanks!

Comment: You have to set up a special webserver to allow free joining the Slack team.

Answer (score 0):

Any noob can use IRC if it's a preconfigured portable mIRC distribution, that connects to your room right after he launches it.

For a status one can rename himself to `John_task1234` on fly.